# Setting up TF Datatset Object with JSON files: Error while parsing JSON

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

So I'm trying to setup my tensorflow dataset object for model input. X is a series of images (.png files) and Y is a series of lists saved in json files.

Everything seems to work well until I go to print some of the dataset elements at the bottom of the code below. I'd like to make sure it worked correctly, but I get an error saying:

```
Error while parsing JSON: : Root element must be a message. [[{{node DecodeJSONExample}}]]{Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

**Some description of the data:**

json files contain a 1D list of various lengths and values that represent points in 3D space. They look like something this:

```
[.28, -.39, .48, 1, 55, 88]
```

Images are in raw format and are (1080, 1920, 3). I hope that helps a little. Let me know if more information is needed.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
def build_dataset():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if path.endswith('.png'):
                x.append(path)
            if path.endswith('.json'):
                y.append(path)
    
     dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
     return dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(x))


def read_data(x_img, y_model):
    img_data = tf.io.read_file(x_img)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img_data)
  
    model_data = tf.io.read_file(y_model)
    model = tf.io.decode_json_example(model_data)
    return img, model

def prepare_data(img, models):
    return img/255, models

train_ds = build_dataset()

train_ds = train_ds.map(read_data)

train_ds = train_ds.map(prepare_data)

train_ds = train_ds.batch(64)

for x, y in train_ds:
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Can you add some dummy data to your question?

Comment: @AloneTogether, I put in a sample of what it looks like. There isn't much, just a1D list in each json file. Could that be the issue? Maybe a dictionary was expected or is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with lists instead of proper JSONs, I would recommend fixing the JSON files. For example:

```
{ "data" : [.28, -.39, .48, 1, 55, 88] ​}
```

Or if you cannot change the files, just read each file and parse it into a tensor without any JSON utilities like `tf.io.decode_json_example`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def read_data(x_img, y_model):
    img_data = tf.io.read_file(x_img)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img_data)
  
    model_data = tf.io.read_file(y_model)
    
    return img, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(tf.strings.regex_replace(tf.strings.strip(model_data), '[\[\],]', '')))

def prepare_data(img, models):
    return img/255, models

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((['/content/result_image.png', '/content/result_image1.png'],
                                              ['/content/test.json', '/content/test2.json']))

train_ds = train_ds.map(read_data)

train_ds = train_ds.map(prepare_data)

train_ds = train_ds.batch(64)

for x, y in train_ds:
    print(x.shape, y)
```

```
(2, 100, 100, 3) tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.28 -0.39  0.48  1.   55.   88.  ]
 [ 0.28 -0.39  0.48  1.   55.   88.  ]], shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: So, adjusting the json files like you suggested above only resulted in a different error. However, the code you posted worked great with the json files as they were. Was the problem solved by converting the list contents to integers?

Comment: Yes that is how it worked.